# How to get Youtube Start, Middle, End, x Sec Thumbnail in maximum resolution

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, extract

I was wondering whether the start, middle and end thumbnails are also available in max resolution?

As descriped in ["How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api) the default thumbnail image is available in max resolution through the url:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg

Start Thumbnail (120x90 pixels)
http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/G0wGs3useV8/1.jpg

Middle Thumbnail (120x90 pixels)
http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/G0wGs3useV8/2.jpg

End Thumbnail (120x90 pixels)
http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/G0wGs3useV8/3.jpg
```

If possible I was wondering whether there are also thumbnails for keyframes say e.g. 10s available?

- I'm aware that his is only possible in case that the video is available in high resolution